# Yii2 RESTful API post() from PUT not returning parameters

Tags: rest, yii2, put

I replaced the standard REST actionUpdate with one that only allows updates to the password:

```
class UserController extends ActiveController
{
    // ...
    public function actions()
    {
        $actions = parent::actions();
        unset($actions['update']);
        return $actions;
    }

    // ...
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        if (! Yii::$app->request->isPut) {
            throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException('Please use PUT');
        }

        /** @var User $user */
        $user = User::findIdentity($id);

        if (Yii::$app->request->post('password') !== null) {
            $user->setPassword(Yii::$app->request->post('password'));
        }

        return $user->save();
    }

    // ...
}
```

[Edit] Here is the User model:

```
<?php
namespace app\models\user;
use Yii;
use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
             implements IdentityInterface
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'Users';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['username', 'password_hash', 'email'], 'required'],
            [['role', 'status'], 'integer'],
            [['username', 'email', 'last_login'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['username'], 'unique'],
            [['email'], 'email'],
            [['auth_key'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
            [['password'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        $return = parent::beforeSave($insert);
        if ($this->isNewRecord)
            $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomKey($length = 255);
        return $return;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne($id);
    }

    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->auth_key;
    }

    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password_hash;
    }

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
    }


    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException('You can only login by username/password pair for now.');
    }

    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
    }
}
```

[/Edit]

Testing with Postman and Codeception, [Response] = true and [Status] = 200.  Both expected.  However, the update does not take.

The [Request] =

```
PUT http://localhost:8888/api/v1/users/1 {"password":"anotherpassword"}
```

...which is correct.  When I print_r the

```
Yii::$app->request->post()
```

in actionUpdate, it returns an empty array.  Model rules lists 'password' as safe.

Any ideas?

Mahalo,
Joe

Comment: can u please post your User model?

Comment: Try to use PATCH HTTP method instead of PUT. I also had problem with PUT request empty payload when testing with Codeception.

Comment: @balaji Posted user model.

Comment: Did you change the lines:
 if (! Yii::$app->request->isPut) {
            throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException('Please use PUT');
        }
to
if (! Yii::$app->request->isPatch) {
            throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException('Please use PATCH');
        }
in the actionUpdate() function?

Comment: @matej PATCH also passes an empty array in post().

Comment: @MatejP.  Yes, I deleted that comment after I noticed the trap.  Still getting empty array, however.

Comment: Sorry I don't see any more reasons why it doesn't work right now. Maybe try to print_r \Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams(), and see if the data are not there. Do you only experience the problem with Codeception or also when trying to send HTTP requests by yourself?

Comment: Thanks for the input @MatejP. getBodyParams() also returns an empty array.  I am testing with both Codeception and Postman.

Comment: did you try to send the data not as a JSON but as a string? "password=anotherpassword&another_param=anotherValue"

Comment: @MatejP. Yes, that is how I am testing it in Postman.  I noticed that when I do a trace, the parameters (id and password) are accessible from the  $_GET global in the controller action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what finally worked for me in case others are interested.  For Postman, I put the Json parameters in the request body (instead of as parameters).

In Codeception, I got my clue [here](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/410).  I had to

```
$I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
```

before $I->sendPUT(...).

Hope this helps the next person...